# Google Compute Engine can't connect my Go app to PostgreSQL base

Tags: postgresql, go, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I work on an application written in Go which uses a PostgreSQL database. I am deploying that app on Google Cloud Platform, for which I chose the Compute Engine service.

I created 2 instances: an instance for running the application and another for the database server. The OS of both instances is Ubuntu 18.04.

When I test the application locally, everything works as expected. Specifically, there are no problems connecting the app with the database.

When I try to run the app on Compute Engine, I get this error:

```
panic: dial tcp 10.132.0.4:5432: connect: connection refused
    goroutine 1 [running]:
main.init.0()
    /home/gauthier/gocode/sprint0/main.go:29 +0x113
exit status 2
```

Here's some information about my VMs:

-VM1(go)

> Internal IP: 10.132.0.3
>    External IP: 35.205.41.152

-VM2(postgreSQL)

> Internal IP: 10.132.0.4
>    External IP: 35.241.174.119

In my app, I connect to the database like this

```
var db *sql.DB

func init() {
    var err error
    db, err =sql.Open("postgres","postgres://postgres:postgres@10.132.0.4/quotes?sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("You connected to your database")
}
```

I cannot find anything in the GCP documentation which fixes this issue.

Comment: No need to give your external IP's here publicly. Secondly can you `ping` both instance locally with each other?

Comment: What about GCE firewall rules - PostgreSQL port 5432 must be opened at least for your go instance. Plus in postgresql.conf you have to set listening to '*' and allow access from IPs in pg_hba.conf.

Comment: @HamzaAnis Yes I can ping both instances locally with the other

Comment: @JosMac I made a Firewall rule like this: https://ibb.co/gvDgNp

Comment: Could you redact your external IP and send me the output of nmap Internal_IP_ADDR of VM2 [from App -> postgresql instance]. Based on the [output of nmap](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html) we can know whether the service is listening.  

Could you add the complete error message (if applicable) and  pg_hba.conf to the question. This is an example where the user had a similar error message due to incorrect pg_hba.conf setting.

Comment: @G.D firewall rule looks generally OK although not exactly safe - for production you definitely do not want to open all protocols and ports :-) - just tcp:5432 for PostgreSQL would be enough. Since you did not specify "target tags" it should work for all instances - for better safety you could specify target tag like "postgresql" and use it for instance with PostgreSQL as "network tag" in VM GCE gui. But any way does it work now?

Comment: Yes it works, thanks a lot to you all :)